# Acumatica API and custom properties

Tags: acumatica

I’m having issues setting custom properties from web service.  I have several string field properties on soline.  When I send a request only some of them are getting set.  I would post the code but there is a lot of extra stuff.

I have checked the web service the payload and the customization.  Everything appears correct anything else I should look at?  Additional info I’m extending the 6.0 web api.  Calling Acumatica from postman.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?
If yes please post your answer so that it can benefit others.
If not please add a sample of code so that we can further help you

Comment: what are the errors? provide more information

Answer (score 0):

So what ended working for me was a series of restarting the application and just entering in the the properties again in the web service.  I would just go one property at a time.  Add it restart the application via 
System -> Management -> Apply Updates -> Restart Application